# UOM not appearing on the second page of form

Tags: abap, livecycle, adobe-form

I have a 2-page Adobe form. In the footer section of master page I have the UOM for totals. When running the form UOM appears in the first page (footer section) but not in the second page. All other data except the UOM are successfully displayed, both in first and second page footer section.

Any idea what I could have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: type of the UOM?

Comment: @Suncatcher I found the solution. Thanks for the interest to help. I have also posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found solution to my problem. Tables are not allowed in master pages, both header and footer, so to make data appear in header and footer of all pages the variable (for example UOM) should be transferred to a global data and then use that global data for data binding.

Hope this helps to those having same issue.